# webBrowse.DrawToBitmap некорректно работает после клика

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Есть код, который сохраняет содержимое `webBrowser` в картинку. Когда я кликаю в содержимое браузера,а именно флеш игра, то после клика сохранненая картинка становится путой, т.е. белый фон и все. С чем это может быть связано?

```
 var bmp = new Bitmap(webBrowser1.Width, webBrowser1.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            webBrowser1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
               webBrowser1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, webBrowser1.Width, webBrowser1.Height));
               bmp.Save(outputDir + "\\" + filename + ".xjpg", ImageFormat.Png);
               bmp.Dispose();

            });
            bmp.Dispose();
```

Comment: а без флеша работает нормально?

Comment: Я даже не пробовал, нужен просто флеш.

Comment: А вы попробуйте. А то как же мы узнаем, в чём проблема?

Comment: попробуйте Graphics.CopyFromScreen. примерно так: создаете bitmap необходимого размера. var bmp = new Bitmap(w,h); var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp); g.CopyFromScreen(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebBrowser - обёртка над неуправляемым компонентом. А метод DrawToBitmap корректно работает только с управляемыми контролами. В его [описании](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserbase.drawtobitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) сказано:

> Данный API поддерживает инфраструктуру .NET Framework и не предназначен для использования непосредственно из кода.

Чтобы этот метод корректно работал, компонент должен отрисовывать своё содержимое вызовом управляемых методов GDI+. WebBrowser отрисовывается неуправляемым кодом.

Тем более, вам нужно получить содержимое флэша. Он отрисовывается самостоятельно внутри браузера, то есть сам браузер не контролирует его вывод напрямую.

Comment: Спасибо за грамотный ответ